# How can I execute « ./bin/pip install -e . » with pip ansible command?

Tags: python, pip, ansible

How can I execute :

```
./bin/pip install -e .
```

With pip ansible command, I don't see this case in doc examples : http://docs.ansible.com/pip_module.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extra_args parameter of the pip module to specify any additional arguments that you want to pass.  Having said that, however, you shouldn't need to explicitly include -e in most cases.  Per the Ansible documentaiton:

```
# Install (MyApp) using one of the remote protocols (bzr+,hg+,git+,svn+). 
# You do not have to supply '-e' option in extra_args.
- pip: name='svn+http://myrepo/svn/MyApp#egg=MyApp'
```

So if you're installing from a remote repository just set the name to be the full URL of the library to install.  And if you want to install a library locally you just specify the full path to the source directory.  The Ansible module does all the rest for you.

Comment: When I tried this with a local path to a directory, I needed to add an extra `-e` option.